# CSS отступ справа при переносе строк

Tags: css

Коллеги, всем привет.

Верстаю не часто, что-то тупняк напал.

Надо сверстать два элемента в строку, в левой колонке какой-то текст. Когда уменьшаем разрешение, текст перестает влазить - переносится на новую строку (это окей), но появляется отсуп справа от текста (это не окей).

В примере второй блок и отсуп справа в красной части. Вот как бы от него избавится.
Сверстать можно как угодно, флексы не принципиальны.

**UPD: Не все поняли. Второй блок ограничен 300px специально, для демонстрации этого эффекта (как-будто мы открыли на мобильном, блок не влез и немного ужался). Естестевенно, на проекте этого нет.**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container max-width">
  <div class="first">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Насколько я представляю, это невозможно без скриптов...

Comment: `word-break: break-all;` только может и один символ от слова перенести на следующую строку..

Comment: Не вижу отступов

Comment: @Arcadiy, смотри лучше...

Comment: Есть какая-то информация по "балансу" ширины левого и правого элементов? "Схлопываться" по ширине контента "умеет" ячейка таблицы. Остальные `display` просто "занимают некое пространство", а контент "размещается" уже "как получится"...

Comment: @ksa В левой части просто текст, занимает столько ширины сколько ему дают. В правой части лежит что-то, что не может быть перенесено на другую строку. В проекте иконка, тут "123". Когда пользователь смотрит на мобилке, текст не влазит, переносится на другую строку и браузер резервирует отсуп справа от текста под слово которое перенёс. Вот, ищу способ от этого избавится без козьего JS костыля.

Comment: А зачем в принципе избавляться от этого отступа? Он режет глаза? На самом деле, если бы его там не было, то блок с текстом заметно прыгал бы при изменеии ширины (когда слово больше не влезает и переносится на новый ряд), и это раздражало бы пользователей намного больше, чем просто немного лишнего места справа.

Comment: @Object417 я с вами полностью согласен. Этого не нужно. Но это есть. Типа "tags", его название (1-3 слова) и потом идет смайлик. Сейчас сверстано флексом и гапом 8px. вот хотят, что-бы когда текст не влазит, он переносился на другую строчку, а отступ от текста до смайлика так и оставался - 8px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из того, что я знаю о формировании блочного контекста, такое сделать на чистом CSS нельзя. Есть костыльное решение с оберткой для инлайн-контента

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.first-modified')
  const width = document.querySelector('.first__inline').offsetWidth + 1 + 'px'
  wrapper.style.width = width
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.first,
.first-modified {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container max-width">
  <div class="first-modified">
    <span class="first__inline">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe 
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Ну, я в целом так и подозревал. Так, думал вдруг что не знаю, хотелось без костыля. Осталось последить за изменением экрана и вуаля. Дам ещё пару дней (вдруг кого осенит) и приму ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, это очень глупо, но что бы не было "отступа" справа от второго блока убери класс `max-width` у элемента оббертки.
Строчные элементы занимают доступное место контента, а этим классом ты строго ограничиваешь расположение элементов. Если тебе просто что б первые колонки были не меньше `300px` то можно гридами сделать.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(300px, 1fr) 1fr;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Привет. Спасибо за ответ. Возможно я как-то не правильно выразился. У этого блока нет ограничения по ширине. Текст в левой части занимает всё доступное пространство. А в правой просто лежит нечто, в нашем примере "123". Проблемы возникают тогда, когда контент в левой части не помещается на экран, например на мобильном. Моё ограничение у второго примера (в 300пикселей в ширину) как раз и демострирует такой пример. Контент в левой части не вошел и слово было перенесено на следующую строчку, а так же, браузер, сделал отступ справа от текста. Вот я ищу способ от него избавиться.

Comment: Что вы хотите что б было с текстом в левой стороне если он не помещаеться? 1)Он переносился на новую строку 2) Он ограничивался. Если первый вариант, то ответ дан, на гридах. Если текст не должен ломать верстку и его отображение не важно. (например технический вывод) можно задать левому блоку `position:relative; overflow:hidden;`

Comment: Привет. Спасибо за ответ! То, что я хочу очень хорошо описано в вопросе. Я хочу чтобы текст перенесся на другую строчку. Вот ваш пример https://rogonov.w3spaces.com/123.html посмотрите его. Сделайте через инспектор ширину экрана 730 пикселей и вы увидите в верхнем блоке, в левой части отступ справа.

Comment: 748 <--> 749 пикселей. вот на этой границе слово переносится и на 748 пикселей и меньше появляется отступ.

Answer (score 2):

update: вариант решения добавлен внизу

---

Сперва хотелось бы узнать, что именно вы хотите увидеть в итоге.

Раз вам не нравится отступ, вам его надо заполнить содержимым (текстом). Текст надо откуда-то взять. Варианты у вас такие:

- Переносить слова тупо по мере достижения ими границы блока (`word-break:break-all`). Выглядит отвратительно.
- Переносить слова по встроенному в браузер словарю (`hyphens:auto`). Это требует указания языка в атрибутах элемента, не во всех браузерах работает в принципе и, разумеется, не сработает для слова, которого в словаре нет.
- Переносить слова по заданным в контенте символам мягкого переноса (`&shy;`). Отлично работает, но сперва нужно подготовить контент - вставить этот символ во все места, где словам разрешено переноситься. То есть, или заранее писать контент с ними (`метил&shy;изо&shy;арсе&shy;нил&shy;гид&shy;ро&shy;хло&shy;рид`), или скриптом расставлять на лету (если напишете скрипт, который сумеет грамматически верно это сделать для любых слов, сможете поднять несколько миллиардов баксов, хех).
- растянуть слова в строке таким образом, чтобы текст был и слева (в начале), и справа (где был отступ) с помощью `text-align:justify`. При этом увеличатся расстояния между словами, и чем меньше слов поместится в строку, тем похабнее выглядит результат.
- попытаться исправить предыдущий пункт, подгоняя расстояние между символами (`letter-spacing`). Но тут может сработать и в обратную сторону - где-нибудь разопрет и вместо  N слов впритык поместится N-1 с разрядкой.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
Оригинал:
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweqqweqqweqweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container max-width">
  <div class="first">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweqqweqqweqweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
<hr> с text-align: justify
<div class="container">
  <div class="first" style="text-align: justify;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweqqweqqweqweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container max-width">
  <div class="first" style="text-align: justify;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweqqweqqweqweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>

с word-break: break-all;
<div class="container ">
  <div class="first" style="word-break: break-all;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweqqweqqweqweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container max-width">
  <div class="first" style="word-break: break-all;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweqqweqqweqweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>

добавляем letter-spacing
<div class="container ">
  <div class="first" style="text-align: justify;    letter-spacing: 0.2vw;    word-break: break-word;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweqqweqqweqweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container max-width">
  <div class="first" style="text-align: justify;    letter-spacing: 0.2vw;    word-break: break-word;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweqqweqqweqweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
уменьшаем красный блок до ширины контента (text-align: justify;    flex:0 0;    overflow-wrap: break-word;):
<div class="container ">
  <div class="first" style="text-align: justify;    flex:0 0;    overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweqqweqqweqweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container max-width">
  <div class="first" style="text-align: justify;    flex:0 0;      overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweqqweqqweqweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>

то же самое, но без длиннющего слова:
<div class="container ">
  <div class="first" style="text-align: justify;    flex:0 0;    overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweq weq weq qweqqwe qweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container max-width">
  <div class="first" style="text-align: justify;    flex:0 0;      overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweq weq weq qweqqwe qweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>

ограничиваем минимальную ширину, а то хрень получается (добавим, например, min-width: 200px;):
<div class="container ">
  <div class="first" style="text-align: justify;    flex:0 0;  min-width: 200px;  overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweq weq weq qweqqwe qweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container max-width">
  <div class="first" style="text-align: justify;    flex:0 0;  min-width: 200px;    overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweq weq weq qweqqwe qweweqwe qweqweqwe qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я хотел бы, чтобы красный блок уменьшился до ширины контента.

Comment: Добавил вариант в конец кода в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Кажется я понял, нужна динамическая ширина первой колонки, чтобы не было отступа, единственное решение без скрипта которое я вижу это использовать `text-align: justify;` - выравнивание как в `Word`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.first {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: justify;
}

.second {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container max-width">
  <div class="first">
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
    qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Рассматривается ли вариант с таблицами?

Ячейка "умеет убирать отступы" и "подстраиваться" под контент. Но нужно как-то разобраться с "балансом" ширины колонок...

Или можно разрешать/запрещать перенос внутри ячейки...

```css
.container {
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.container td {
vertical-align: top;
}
.first {
width: 1%;
white-space: nowrap;
background-color: red;
}
.max-width .first {
width: 1%;
white-space: normal;
background-color: red;
}

.second {
background-color: yellow;
}

.max-width {
max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table class='container'>
    <tr>
        <td class='first'>qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe</td>
        <td class='second'>123</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class='container max-width'>
    <tr>
        <td class='first'>qweqweqweqweq qweqweqwe qweqweqwe</td>
        <td class='second'>123</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: я так понимаю, это тоже самое, что в его пример добавить  .container.max-width .first { flex: 0 0 0; }

Comment: Привет. Спасибо за ответ! Да, пробовал. Но видишь, тебе пришлось вкрячивать white-space: nowrap в первую таблицу, а нужно сделать так, что если ширина экрана позволяет, то текст отоброжается весь, а если не позволяет, то переносится на другую строчку.